# Can I count elements within one div with .length() instead of whole document? - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've just finished making a nice Amazon-style "review summary" counter for an ecommerce store. It uses part of the 'stars' image file names to count reviews with .length() which works great but the issue is it is also counting these images from other sections of the page (such as related products, add to cart section). These areas use the same "stars" images as the review section so the counts are off.

e.g. on this page - http://www.siestahammocks.com.au/single-size-brazilian-hammock/ there are only two 5 star reviews and one 4 star review, yet it is counting eight 5 star reviews and three 4 star reviews due to the related products section using the same star images (further down) and the stars are used once more near the top of the page.

I can rectify this problem if I can find a way to count the star images based on the div they sit in, rather than counting the amounts of them in the whole document.

I need what sets the variables in the var count1/2/3/4/5 to be a bit different I think.

Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Here's my current script:

```
 <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
var count1 = $('img[src$="IcoRating1.png"]').length;
var count2 = $('img[src$="IcoRating2.png"]').length;
var count3 = $('img[src$="IcoRating3.png"]').length;
var count4 = $('img[src$="IcoRating4.png"]').length;
var count5 = $('img[src$="IcoRating5.png"]').length;
$('.revcount1').append(count1);
$('.revcount2').append(count2);
$('.revcount3').append(count3);
$('.revcount4').append(count4);
$('.revcount5').append(count5);

var reviewtotal = count1 + count2 + count3 + count4 + count5;

    var counter1 = count1 / reviewtotal *100;
    var counter2 = count2 / reviewtotal *100;
    var counter3 = count3 / reviewtotal *100;
    var counter4 = count4 / reviewtotal *100;
    var counter5 = count5 / reviewtotal *100;

    $(".counter-bar5").css("width",counter5,"px");
    $(".counter-bar4").css("width",counter4,"px");
    $(".counter-bar3").css("width",counter3,"px");
    $(".counter-bar2").css("width",counter2,"px");
    $(".counter-bar1").css("width",counter1,"px");


});
        </script>
```

Comment: Are you looking for the [`.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/) jQuery function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would return the image count for that image just in a div with ID `myDiv`.

```
var count1 = $('#myDiv img[src$="IcoRating1.png"]').length;
```

Comment: Hmm this didn't seem to work. Does it need to be the immediate parent of where the images sit?

Comment: No, just a [descendant](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) of that div, a child selector would be `$('#myDiv>img[src$="IcoRating1.png"]')`. If you provide some markup in your question it may help.

Comment: Sorry, your initial answer totally worked. I was adding it only to the 1 star count variable and checking the 5 star for output. Noob mistake. Just tried it across all and works perfectly. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0):

`$("#your-div").children().length`

should return just the immediate children count

Here's the doc : https://api.jquery.com/children/

Quoted from that source :

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well. Note also that like most jQuery methods, .children()
>   does not return text nodes; to get all children including text and
>   comment nodes, use .contents().

Comment: Would i then put the image file name selector in between the children parentheses? Because I need the counts of each type of review. e.g. total 5 star reviews, total 4 star reviews etc.. Which works based on the IcoRating5.png type of selector.. Are you suggesting this? - $("#your-div").children('img[src$="IcoRating1.png"]').length

Answer (score 0):

Your star images are nested within a `<h4>` with the class "ReviewTitle", so you could do `$('.ReviewTitle > img[src$="IcoRating5.png"]').length`, instead of creating a new div with a new class or ID. This will only bring back the children of .ReviewTitle then select the image as you have already done. It's a little more compact than `.children()` too. I've tested it on your page and it seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for your input mate. I actually ended up using this var count1 = $('ol.ProductReviewList img[src$="IcoRating1.png"]').length; which is similar to what you're suggesting - no need for extra divs or classes as they were already using this one. Cheers.